# Taking first step for learning C lang. with MAC

Tags: c, xcode, macos, sublimetext3

Before moving on to question, I'm 100% newbie to programming and I'm on my own.
So please answer my question even though you think it seems very silly.

Somehow I manage to install command line tools successfully:

```
LazyRen:~ LazyRen$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
LazyRen:~ LazyRen$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
LazyRen:~ LazyRen$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
```

But the problem is when I tried to build the most basic codes with ST3 it gives me

```
clang: error: no input files
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['gcc', 'Hello C World!', '-o', 'Hello C World!']]
[dir: /Users/LazyRen/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

This.
I just have no idea what kind of input file is needed. Any hints?

Comment: C programs are usually written as text files containing the source code, whose names end with `.c`. You seem to be trying to compile a file called `'Hello C World!'`, which doesn't exist. Try saving your source code to a file like `hello.c` and then compiling that.

Comment: This beginner's guide should get you on your way (see the Hello World in C section): http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/C/lectures/module1/module1.html

Comment: it works! I will see the site. Thank you. The book I am reading was written for window VS so it wasn't helping me at all.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be lost inside ST3. As you have Xcode why not use it instead? To run a command line "Hello World" C program do the following:

1. Open Xcode
2. Select **File > New > Project...**
3. On the left side select **Application** under **OS X**
4. On the right select **Command Line Tool**
5. Press **Next**
6. Fill the 3 text fields with "hello" "LazyRen" & "com.lazyren" - these at not important in this situation, but the **Next** button won't be enabled till you fill them in.
7. In the **Type** menu select **C**
8. Press **Next**
9. In the standard save dialog locate the folder you wish to store your code in and then press **Create**
10. Project will now open in Xcode, select **main.c** on the left. On doing that the large editing area will show the starting template - which just happens to be "Hello World!"
11. Select **Product > Run** - you've run your first command line C program. Output will appear in a small window.

Now continue with your C textbook. Also look at the Xcode documentation. In the latter you will find out how to locate the code you just compiled on the disc to you can run it from **Terminal** if you wish.

HTH